# Xamarin Live Player

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, xamarin-live-player

Unable to deploy to Asus ASUS_Z01BDB Player, please ensure the Xamarin Live Player app is open and the device is on the same network as Visual Studio.
Failed to debug your app.

The error with other project was just connecting and say connected and after 2 sec the qr-code on the computer changes and mobile displays connection lost. it is continued automatically like a infinite loop.

Visual Studio Community 15.6.1

Xamarin Live Player 1.5.176

Internet Connection is available with WiFi.

Computer and Phone is connected to same WiFi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by :Goto Tools>Extensions and Updates> Updates. And Click to Update the Visual Studio Cumulative Update which will be on the list. Esure your network connection

Some others find a solution by Xamarin for visual Studio, XamarinApple SDK, Xamarin Android SDK, Mono Debugging for Visual Studio which is on the list.

So i would encourage you to keep the list empty.

Try with the build available in the fast ring? For information on how to join the fast ring for Xamarin Live Player, please see here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/install/#Xamarin_Live_Player_Fast_Ring